# How to unit test a method which does not return anything with phpunit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am fresher working in PHP and I want to unit test a method which does not returns anything but just sets value to an object. My code is like this

```
class User
{
    private $name;

    private $email;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

   public function setName(?string $name): void
   {
       $this->name = $name;
   }

   public function getEmail(): ?string
   {
      return $this->email;
   }

   public function setEmail(?string $email): void
   {
       $this->email = $email;
   }
}
```

The class I want to test is like this

```
class UserMapper
{
    public function map(User $user): void
    {
          $user->setName("abc");
          $user->setemail("abc@example.com")
    }
}
```

How can I test this map function with PHPUnit mock?

Comment: test $user after the method call if has the values

Comment: Why don't you get the values afterwards and perform a normal comparison vi `==` or `===`? (Whichever is appropiate).

Comment: The duplicate raises some interesting points about this sort of testing, but the last answer also shows you how you can do it.